# grepl multiple combinations without loop in r

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, combinations, grepl

BIG EDIT - Trying to simplify the output and question**

I have an issue extracting combinations of variables out of a previous set of combinations (there may be an easier way but this was my cluncky way of getting this done with grepl and a loop).

It works but it takes a long time with a larger dataset and I can't find an answer with `And` as criteria without a loop.

In this example, I'm trying to eliminate every group from "comb1" that contains a combination of 3 of the "comb".

Here is my code if anyone can help. Much appreciated

```
mydata <- read.csv("Test.csv", sep=",", header=FALSE)
n1 <- 4
comb1 <- combn(mydata,n1,simplify=FALSE)
tofind <- c("V1 ","V3 ","V4","V6") 
n2 <- 3
comb2 <- combn(tofind,n2)
temp <- list(data=NA,ncol=dim(comb2)[2])
for (j in 1:dim(comb2)[2]){
  temp[[j]] <- which(grepl(comb2[1,j],comb1) & grepl(comb2[2,j],comb1) & grepl(comb2[3,j],comb1))
}
Remove <- sort(unique(unlist(temp)),decreasing=FALSE)
comb <- comb1[-Remove]
```

`mydata`:

```
> mydata
      V1     V2      V3      V4      V5      V6     V7      V8      V9     V10
1      A      B       C       D       E       F      G       H       I       J
2 0.0908 0.0937  0.0871  0.0557  0.0144  0.0005 0.0189  0.0053  0.0154 -0.0021
3 0.0603   0.05  0.1312 -0.0204 -0.0186 -0.0256 0.0033 -0.0178  -0.014 -0.0686
4 0.0234 0.0144 -0.0955 -0.0076 -0.0101  0.0152 0.0215  0.0036 -0.0031   0.006
5 0.0385 -0.004 -0.1423  0.0479 -0.0013 -0.0109 0.0172  0.0277   0.005  0.0296
```

EDIT - Thanks @MLavoie, here is `dput` of my shortened `mydata`

```
> dput(mydata)
structure(list(V1 = structure(c(5L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("0.0234", 
"0.0385", "0.0603", "0.0908", "A"), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(c(5L, 
4L, 3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("-0.004", "0.0144", "0.05", "0.0937", 
"B"), class = "factor"), V3 = structure(c(5L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("-0.0955", 
"-0.1423", "0.0871", "0.1312", "C"), class = "factor"), V4 = structure(c(5L, 
4L, 2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("-0.0076", "-0.0204", "0.0479", "0.0557", 
"D"), class = "factor"), V5 = structure(c(5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("-0.0013", 
"-0.0101", "-0.0186", "0.0144", "E"), class = "factor"), V6 = structure(c(5L, 
3L, 2L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("-0.0109", "-0.0256", "0.0005", "0.0152", 
"F"), class = "factor"), V7 = structure(c(5L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("0.0033", 
"0.0172", "0.0189", "0.0215", "G"), class = "factor"), V8 = structure(c(5L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("-0.0178", "0.0036", "0.0053", "0.0277", 
"H"), class = "factor"), V9 = structure(c(5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("-0.0031", 
"-0.014", "0.005", "0.0154", "I"), class = "factor"), V10 = structure(c(5L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("-0.0021", "-0.0686", "0.006", "0.0296", 
"J"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", 
"V5", "V6", "V7", "V8", "V9", "V10"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

**The code works with the way I grab the data and its format, but the problem is the sequence: `which(grepl(combM[1,j],comb1) & grepl(combM[2,j],comb1) & grepl(combM[3,j],comb1))` It's quick in this small example, but it takes a long time with a bigger dataset**

Comment: Could you provide `mydata` to make everything reproducible?

Comment: Looks to me that you screwed up your own data input. Should have used `read.table` with `header =TRUE`. The way you did it converted everything to character.

Comment: I used `read.csv` to import from a csv and what I posted seems to work, I may have pasted improperly the data from r. My issue is that the loop seems to slow tremendously when I use more columns and I can't seem to find a solution without it

Comment: to include your dataset in your post, run in R dput(dataset) and copy the content in your post